# Understanding Gephi statistics

Tags: data-visualization

Modularity: I understand that modularity is supposed to represent sophistication of structure on a macro level, but what does it mean on the individual level?

Page Rank: I'm dealing with a dataset of people asking questions and answering questions. If someone answers a question, the arrow is drawn from the person who asked the question to the person who answered the question. If an individual has a high page rank value in this situation, what does that mean?

Force Atlas 2: I have no idea how this works compared to the other layout algorithms.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 10):

I'm using Gephi 0.8.1. Here's some information about the meanings of these statistics.

[Modularity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modularity_%28networks%29) has to do with dividing the network into communities. Most community detection algorithms try to maximise the modularity. It's important to realise that what the algorithm is actually doing is trying to find a partition of the nodes into communities, in such a way that the modularity is large. The modularity measures how many links within communities there are, compared to how many links between communities there are. This is hard to maximise because there are many, many possible partitions of the network into communities, so the algorithm could easily miss the best one. But it usually find something sensible.

Running this on the Les Miserables example which ships with Gephi, the maximum value of the modularity it finds is 0.558. The graphic it produces shows the sizes of the six communities which it finds. You can find out which nodes are in these communities by using the partition tab.

Modularity has no meaning on the individual level; nodes don't have a modularity, they are just classified, or clustered, into communities by the algorithm.

[Pagerank](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PageRank) is a measure of importance, or how central someone is within the network. It's roughly based on random walks; someone who is randomly following the edges of the network is likely to arrive at you eventually if you have a high Pagerank score. So, for example, if you search for Pagerank in Google, the Wikipedia page on Pagerank is near the top, because people who are trying to find out about Pagerank are likely to arrive at that page by clicking on links from other pages which mention Pagerank.

The Pagerank algorithm is fairly understandable. I am fond of the book *Programming Collective Intelligence*, which explains how it can be implemented.

For your questioners and answerers example, I am not too sure what kind of data set you might be looking at, so I can't give you a sensible reply.

Force Atlas 2 is a complicated algorithm for how to lay out your graph. It's based on the idea that you will get a nice picture of the graph if you assume that the edges are springs and the nodes are magnets which repel each other. Then the nodes will be well-spread out but the edges won't be too long. By simulating this spring/magnet system, it gives you a good picture of your graph. You can see it running if you have the Overview window open when it is running.. For the Les Miserables example, make sure you set repulsion strength to something high. I used 100000 and it gave me a nice visualisation. There are so many options in Force Atlas 2 that it might be better just to look at [an existing tutorial](https://gephi.org/2011/forceatlas2-the-new-version-of-our-home-brew-layout/) which offers some explanation of the various parameters which you can tweak.

Comment: +1 That's a great reply to an otherwise opaque set of questions.  Thanks for making sense of this.